# If condition in Talend

Tags: database, etl, talend

I have an if condition and else in my job. After that I should have a customized mapping depending on whether it goes to the if or the else. Is there a way to make the part after the if and else run when the if condition is checked. I dont want to connect it to the if and else, since it becomes a lot and it crashes.

Lets say I have filewatcher-->tdbinput--> global variable --> if condition and else (I already have things after If and else) if I do the below also ill have many if's and else's

if global variable is equal to sth I want to map the tinputdelimited in a way, and if else I want to map it in another way

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your job? Also state where you want the condition.

Comment: I think you'll need two subjobs, one for each of your conditional branch, as the schema of your tFileInputDelimited will be different in each branch.